# RequestFeature must be called before adding content, unsure why it's being called

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I am currently trying to have an AlertDialog box pop up with information regarding a movie with the custom layout file "details.xml" I feel it may be how I am populating these fields with regards to the AlertDialog, but I am unsure how best to handle it.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> Parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Movie mTemp = movieArray.get(position);             
            //Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleItemList.class);

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MovieList.this);
            builder.setView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.details, null));
            builder.setTitle("Details");
            builder.setNeutralButton("Post to Facebook", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // User clicked OK button
                }
            });
            AlertDialog d = builder.create();
            if (mTemp != null) {
                ImageView image = (ImageView) d.findViewById(R.id.detailIcon);
                TextView title = (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.detailTitle);
                TextView year = (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.detailYear);
                TextView rating = (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.detailRating);
                TextView director = (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.detailDirector);

                if (title != null) {
                    title.setText("Name: " + mTemp.title);
                }

                if(year != null) {
                    year.setText("Year: " + mTemp.year);
                }

                if(rating != null) {
                    rating.setText("Rating: " + mTemp.rating + "/10");
                }

                if(director != null) {
                    director.setText("Director: " + mTemp.director);
                }

                if(image != null) {
                    image.setImageBitmap(getBitmap(mTemp.coverURL));
                }
            }

            d.show();

            /*
            Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MovieList.this);
            dialog.setTitle("Details");
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.details);


            dialog.show();*/
        }
});
```

Comment: Where in your code is requestFeature being called?

Comment: I never called it, the error just started showing up once I began adding the AlertDialog

Comment: Then how are you sure it is being called? The android underlying system may call certain methods because that's how android works. Dialogs need to request a window to not have a title among other things. Please elaborate more in your question, it is very vague. What are you trying to handle? What is your actual problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't posted your LogCat errors but I assume that it is your `(mTemp != null)` block that is causing trouble. Alter the inflated View, then pass it to `setView()`.

```
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.details, null);
if (mTemp != null) {
    ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.detailIcon);
    TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.detailTitle);
    ...
}

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MovieList.this);
builder.setTitle("Details");
builder.setView(view);
builder.setNeutralButton("Post to Facebook", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // User clicked OK button
            }
        });

AlertDialog d = builder.create();
d.show();
```

Comment: That must have been it as it's been fixed now. Thank you!