# App crashes on some devices because InflateException: #19: Error inflating class ImageView or "requestFeature() must be called before adding content"

Tags: android, imageview, inflate-exception

App crashes on some devices because of layout issues.

Now only VIVO Y66 (Android 6.0.1, API 23) crashes.

If the fragment contains image, it will get InflateException error:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class ImageView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:545)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
        at com.abacus.newonlineordering.view.fragment.RoyaltyPointsFragment.onCreateView(RoyaltyPointsFragment.java:87)
        at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2220)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148)
        at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:482)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5619)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:853)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:737)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class ImageView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:827)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:749)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:880)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:843)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:883)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:843)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:883)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:843)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:521)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
        at com.abacus.newonlineordering.view.fragment.RoyaltyPointsFragment.onCreateView(RoyaltyPointsFragment.java:87) 
        at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2220) 
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973) 
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148) 
        at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793) 
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535) 
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:482) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5619) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:853) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.abacus.newonlineordering:drawable/barcode" (7f070061) is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f070061 a=-1 r=0x7f070061}
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2668)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2606)
        at android.content.res.VivoResources.loadDrawable(VivoResources.java:220)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:152)
        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:140)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:71)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:67)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:181)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:105)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1035)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1092)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:791)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:880) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:843) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:883) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:843) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:883) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:843) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:521) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
        at com.abacus.newonlineordering.view.fragment.RoyaltyPointsFragment.onCreateView(RoyaltyPointsFragment.java:87) 
        at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2220) 
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973) 
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148) 
        at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793) 
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535) 
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:482) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5619) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:853) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:737)
```

If the fragment has popup dialog, it will get the following error:

```
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:352)
        at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:264)
        at android.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:433)
        at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:394)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:295)
        at com.abacus.newonlineordering.tool.Utils.showAlertDialog(Utils.java:130)
        at com.abacus.newonlineordering.view.fragment.SettingFragment.showConfirmMsg(SettingFragment.java:274)
        at com.abacus.newonlineordering.view.fragment.SettingFragment.access$100(SettingFragment.java:53)
        at com.abacus.newonlineordering.view.fragment.SettingFragment$2.onClick(SettingFragment.java:259)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5212)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21214)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5619)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:853)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:737)
```

The App works fine on other devices.

Comment: what kind of image do you use? Which format? Can you show the XML? Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **drawable/barcode** (7f070061) **is not a Drawable** (**color or path**):

Removing such file which called `barcode` from drawables will help since it's not a `drawable` - **color or path**.

> requestFeature() must be called **before adding content at**

Don't call `setContentView()` or `onCreateView()` before `requestFeature()`

**Check this out:** [requestFeature() must be called before adding content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250149/requestfeature-must-be-called-before-adding-content)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found the app crashes because I put images in drawable-v24. I fix it by moving them into drawable. I resolved the second issue referring to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575750/requestfeature-must-be-called-before-adding-content-unsure-why-its-being-calle

Comment: Since you didn't paste any codes, I'd assumed that `barcode` from drawables might cause the issue. However, you can mark this answer as an accepted one if it helped.